# How can I have different responses for different platforms of the same intent using fulfillment

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I want to have a certain condition for checking. If it gives true, I want the bot to make a phone call and if not - synthesize a specific message. If the platform doesn't support phone calls, just show some text without checking a condition.
It is pretty easy to have different responses for different platforms of the same intent in the intent constructor itself, but if i enable a fulfillment for this intent, it becomes difficult. I know, it is possible to add a text like

```
agent.add("text here")
```

and it will show text message. I would like to have different responses for this intent depending on the platform, but I didn't find any fields in the webhook client docs for this feature (like agent.platforms). I would also like to be able to make a phone call from fulfillment. I tried to replace a text message with a json object like:

```
agent.add({
  "facebook": {
    "text":"hi123"
  },
  "hangouts": {
  },
  "kik": {
  },
  "line": {
  },
  "skype": {
  },
  "slack": {
  },
  "telegram": {
  },
  "viber": {
  }
});
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify dynamic responses with  `agent.add()`, it is simply for adding text to the agent response.

You'll need to use a custom payload to generate integration-specific responses, as described on this page: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-rich-messages